# UnicodeScalar string has no value property in swift 3.0

Tags: iphone, swift3, xcode8

In swift 2.0 i had written below function that was working fine.

```
private func escape(string: String) -> String {
        let unicode = string.unicodeScalars
        var newString = ""
        for i in unicode.startIndex ..< unicode.endIndex {
            let char = unicode[i]
            if char.value < 9 || (char.value > 9 && char.value < 32) // < 32 == special characters in ASCII, 9 == horizontal tab in ASCII
                || char.value == 39 { // 39 == ' in ASCII
                let escaped = char.escape(asASCII: true)
                newString.appendContentsOf(escaped)
            } else {
                newString.append(char)
            }
        }
        return newString
    }
```

But after update to Xcode 8 and Swift 3.0 my code has error that **unicodeScalars** has no property .value to access unicode value of a character. So what is the new property for the same in Swift3.0?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may be?

```
   private func escape(string : String) -> String {

        var newString = ""

        string.unicodeScalars.forEach { char in

            let expression = (char.value > 9 && char.value < 32)
            (char.value < 9) || expression || (char.value == 39) ?  newString.append(char.escaped(asASCII: true)) : newString.append(String(char))
        }

        return newString
    }
```